# How to do form authentication in Silverlight Web Application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight

I am developing a silverlight web application.I want to use form authentication in it.Can anyone help?

Comment: This Thread can be help full for you ...... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11889877/forms-authentication-for-a-silverlight-application-in-windows-azure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve form authentication, you should follow these steps:

1) **define a service** (or some extra functions in your existing WCF service) to perform user management operations: create new user, authenticate user (by username and password), logout. The service requires a user table in the data tier (e.g. SQL Server) to hold username (e-mail), encrypted passwords and other information

2) **define a register new user interface** (username/e-mail, password, other information, if necessary).

3) **define login interface** (username/e-mail and password)

4) **allow logout**

5) **(recommended) have a forgot password interface** (e-mail must be used when registering the user or something else to allow the challenge - i.e. phone number, to send a SMS with a code)

6) **implement security** throughout your Silverlight pages: each service call from non-public section must check if the user is logged in and has the appropriate rights

In order to avoid doing all these steps from scratch, I recommend you to read this [walk-through](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942449(v=vs.91).aspx). It seems to cover all the basics.